# How to store birthdays in Outlook that doesn't show me as busy

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar, appointments

I have birthdays saved in Outlook as recurring "All day events" (that recur yearly) and mark then private. The problem is that when I share my calendar, the person just sees "private appointment" that lasts the whole day, when it's just a birthday reminder for me.

Is there a way to indicate that these events so I'm not seen as busy the whole day? Is there a better way to store birthdays?

I'm using Outlook 2010 with Exchange (not sure of the version)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Outlook appointments have a `Show Time As` option.

Set this to `Free` and others will still see the `Private Appointment` but it will not list you as `Busy` for the day.

This screenshot is for Outlook 2003 but the same option is there in Outlook 2010:

[image: Outlook 2003 Show Time As]

Comment: I was under the impression that `Free` events did not show on the free/busy info presented to other users (unless you've got full calendar sharing).